# Multiplicative inverse of (x-y) in a Field

Tags: field-theory, inverse

Consider $x, y \in F$ where F is a Field and $0 \neq x \neq y \neq 0$. What is the multiplicative(!) inverse of $(x-y) \in F$ ?

I'm struggling to work this out...

Comment: Does the field is given?

Comment: No, the field is not otherwise specified.

Comment: Then it's $\frac{1}{x-y}$? I mean, what kind of answer are you really expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Unless $F$ is specified, the only reasonable answer is: it is the unique element $u\in F$ satisfying $(x-y)u=1$.

You cannot expect any general formula working for any field.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = -x$ (which is possible under the assumption that $x \neq y$ only if $char(F) \neq 2$), then $(x - y)^{-1} = (2x)^{-1}$. Else $y \neq x, -x$ and so $y^2 \neq x^2$. Then $(x - y)^{-1} = (x + y)/(x^2 - y^2)$.

Comment: and then, one may ask: what is the inverse of $x^2-y^2$ ?

Comment: @GreginGre that's a really good point. I didn't realize my question was not adding anything substantial